# How to delete all text after certain character in MS Word?

Tags: ms-word

let's say I have text like this:

> Something something: what what what
>
> another something something: another whhaa

So I want to delete text after character **:** on each line, so I end up with:

> Something something
>
> another something something

is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but if we're talking about lines (as opposed to paragraphs) not 100% reliable. Word doesn't consider a "line" as a tangible object since it's always recalculating the page flow (where things break across lines/pages). Paragraphs are objects since ANSI 13 defines the end of a paragraph.

Here's some VBA code that demonstrates the literal interpretation of your request. The part through Find.Execute was made by recording using Word's Find functionality. The last three lines extend the selection to the end of the current line, move it back by one character to leave the new line / end of paragraph intact. then delete the selection. This should give you a starting point.

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ":"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchByte = False
    .CorrectHangulEndings = False
    .HanjaPhoneticHangul = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.MoveEnd wdLine, 1
Selection.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
Selection.Delete
```